# What does minimal and maximal number of statements mean in the Structural Search & Replace tool

Tags: resharper

In Resharper there is a structural search and replace tool.

If I were to add a placeholder for example an "Argument", on the "Create Argument Placeholder" dialog it has a checkbox to "limit minimal number of arguments" and "Maximal".

What exactly does this do?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the argument placeholder matches any number of arguments. The checkboxes allow you to limit how many arguments it matches. Minimal is the least number of arguments, and maximal is the most number of arguments.

So, given a pattern like:

```
DoSomething($args$);
```

where `$args$` is an argument placeholder without anything checked, it would match all of the following:

```
a) DoSomething("hello world");
b) DoSomething("hello", "world");
c) DoSomething("hello", "world", "this", "has", "more", "parameters");
```

If you set the minimal (least) number of args to 2, it would only match b and c. If you also set the maximal (most) number to 5, it would only match b.

You'll see that the description reflects what's going on: "any number of arguments", or "at least 2 and not more than 5 arguments".